# How does a bound asp.net gridview work with html5 offline

Tags: asp.net, html, offlineapps

I am looking at the best way to make my asp.net web forms application be available offline.
A lot of the controls are bound to a linqdatasource.
What would need to be done to make these bound control available to go offline?

Comment: Fair bit of work needs to be done. For details see at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786303/offline-mode-app-in-a-html5-browser-possible

Comment: The question was helpful, but I need to know about databound controls.  Would I need to unhook these controls from their datasource or do you just keep checking to see if the internet goes offline and then create a new datasource from localstorage.  I am just learning about this and would like some feedback from those of you that know more about this.